# State space model equation

Tags: linear, state-space-models, quadratic-form

I would appreciate your help on the following

I have a quadratic equation and need to write it in a state space format according to a model below. My equation is the following below, where T is the degree of a custom index persistency and Z a vector of control variables.

[image]

The target state space model is

[image]

comes from eq 33 in Canova and Ciccarelli (2013),a paper in economics (https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecbwp1507.pdf) .

Could you please be of help on how to write the quadratic polynomial in the above  state space form?